# variation on printing combinations of balanced parentheses

Tags: python, counting, parentheses

Given a string of left and right parentheses (I write as a string of L's and R's, and there aren't necessarily equal number of L's and R's). I need to count the number of possible balanced parenthetical expressions including nesting. So for a small example, if we have s = L1L2R1R2L3R3R4,

null, L1R1, L1R2, L1R3, L1R4, L2R1, L2R2, L2R3, L2R4, L3R3, L3R4, L1R2L3R3, L1R2L3R4, L2R1L3R3, L2R1L3R4, L1R2L3R3, L1R2L3R4, L2R2L3R3, L2R2L3R4, L1L2R1R2L3R3, L1L2R1R2L3R4

21 possible expressions. I have seen a couple of answers here concerning n pairs of left and right parentheses, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. How can I write a python program for this? I have not programmed much before so I'm trying to at least get some pseudocode down.

Comment: You’ve told us what you need, but not asked a question. Show us what you’ve tried so far and where you’re stuck. Look at [ask], then provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html; good luck with the pseudocode